# Меняется значение атрибута класса Python

Tags: python-3.x

Почему меняется значение атрибута класса Cell.value?

```
class Cell:

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None

    def show(self):
        print(self.value)
        
    def change_value(self,val):
        self.value = val

class Sudoku:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.pos = [[Cell()]*9]*9
        self.flag = False

    def set_value(self, x, y, value):
        self.pos[x][y].change_value(value)
        print(self.pos[x][y].value)

    def get_value(self, x, y):
        return self.pos[x][y].value

a.set_value(8,1,2)
a.set_value(8,3,5)
a.set_value(8,8,6)
a.pos[8][1].show()
print(a.get_value(8,3))

2
5
6
6
6
```

Значение a.pos[8][1].value при вызове метода set_value принимает значение 5, но потом принимает значение 6.
От куда взялась эта 6 и почему поменялось значение?

Comment: Потому что эта строка заполняет всю сетку одним и тем же объектом, а не создает новый объект для каждой ячейки: `self.pos = [[Cell()]*9]*9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте прочитаем ваш код по порядку его выполнения (объявление классов и их методов опустим, пойдём по порядку):

```
a.set_value(8, 1, 2)
```

Видим обращение к `class Sudoku, method: set_value`, читаем: он меняет у некоторой "координаты" переменной `pos` (а именно `pos[8][1]`) переменную `value`.
Рассмотрим то, как вы объявили переменную `pos` (`self.pos` у класса `Sudoku`):

`[[Cell()]*9]*9` и вся проблема кроется именно в этой строке. Вы как бы не создаёте отдельно новую `Cell()` для каждого места в двумерном списке, а копируете 81 раз одну и ту же. В итоге выходит, что к какому бы месту вы не обращались в `self.pos`, вы всегда обращаетесь к одному и тому же объекту.

Реализовать можно по разному заполнение `self.pos`:

Можно взять банально написать

`self.pos = [ [Cell(), Cell(), ..., Cell()], [Cell(), Cell(), ..., Cell()], ..., [Cell(), Cell(), ..., Cell()]]`, но мы ведь с вами хотим покрасивее, полагаю?

Например:

```
...
self.pos = []
for i in range(9):
    part_of_pos = []
    for j in range(9):
        part_of_pos.append(Cell())
    self.pos.append(part_of_pos)
...
```

Впрочем, вы ошибку, полагаю, поняли, дальше уже только ваша фантазия!

---

Всем добра

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Когда лег спать, понял свою ошибку! :)

Comment: Да простят меня модераторы за не совсем по теме комментарий, но обычно решения приходят после пробуждения или перед сном, не знаю, как это работает)